# PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare frm_dl() wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i'm having a 500 internal server problem. http://www.bunchmag.com/

```
500 internal server error Fatal error: Cannot redeclare frm_dl
```

> 20130329T141539: www.bunchmag.com/index.php PHP Fatal error: Cannot
>   redeclare frm_dl() (previously declared in
>   /hermes/web09/aksjhfks/moo.bunchmagazinecom/bunch/index.php(1) :
>   eval()'d code:1) in
>   /hermes/web09/skjfljf/moo.bunchmagazinecom/bunch/wp-config.php(1) :
>   eval()'d code on line 10

my hosting tech support is working on it but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you have 2 or more functions name frm_dl? either multiple plugins, or a file being included twice?

Comment: Do you have any custom code that's including a function that's already declared previously?  If you're including a file several times (which you shouldn't do), use `include_once` instead of `include`.  It makes PHP use a little intelligence to only include a file once.

Comment: It may also help to wrap the function in an if statement: if(!function_exists("frm_dl") ){...}

Comment: What are lines #05 to #15 in `wp-config.php`?

Answer (score 0):

Locate where the function is being declared and wrap it in an if statement to ensure the function is not already declared.

```
if( !function_exists( "frm_dl" ) ){
    function frm_dl(..){
        ...
    }
}
```

this should solve the issue if its the same file being included twice.

alternatively, search for multiple files declaring the function and wrap each one in the conditional statement, or change on of the function names (if possible)